# How to implement convolution algorithm with SSE?

Tags: c++, simd, sse, convolution

```
const int INPUT_SIGNAL_ARRAY_SIZE = 256896;
const int IMPULSE_RESPONSE_ARRAY_SIZE = 318264;
const int OUTPUT_SIGNAL_ARRAY_SIZE = INPUT_SIGNAL_ARRAY_SIZE + IMPULSE_RESPONSE_ARRAY_SIZE;

__declspec(align(16)) float inputSignal_dArray[INPUT_SIGNAL_ARRAY_SIZE];
__declspec(align(16)) float impulseResponse_dArray[IMPULSE_RESPONSE_ARRAY_SIZE];
__declspec(align(16)) float outputSignal_dArray[OUTPUT_SIGNAL_ARRAY_SIZE];
```

I have method that works correct and produces some correct values:

```
//#pragma optimize( "", off )
void computeConvolutionOutputCPU(float* inputSignal, float* impulseResponse, float* outputSignal) {
    float* pInputSignal = inputSignal;
    float* pImpulseResponse = impulseResponse;
    float* pOutputSignal = outputSignal;

    #pragma loop(no_vector)
    for (int i = 0; i < OUTPUT_SIGNAL_ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        *(pOutputSignal + i) = 0;

        #pragma loop(no_vector)
        for (int j = 0; j < IMPULSE_RESPONSE_ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (i - j >= 0 && i - j < INPUT_SIGNAL_ARRAY_SIZE)
            {
                *(pOutputSignal + i) = *(pOutputSignal + i)  + *(pImpulseResponse + j) *  (*(pInputSignal + i - j));
            }
        }
    }
}
//#pragma optimize( "", on )
```

On the other hand I should use function with SSE. I tried the following code, but the output not the same:

```
void computeConvolutionOutputSSE(float* inputSignal, float* impulseResponse, float* outputSignal) {
    __m128* pInputSignal = (__m128*) inputSignal;
    __m128* pImpulseResponse = (__m128*) impulseResponse;
    __m128* pOutputSignal = (__m128*) outputSignal;


    int nOuterLoop = OUTPUT_SIGNAL_ARRAY_SIZE / 4;
    int nInnerLoop = IMPULSE_RESPONSE_ARRAY_SIZE / 4;
    int quarterOfInputSignal = INPUT_SIGNAL_ARRAY_SIZE / 4;

    __m128 m0 = _mm_set_ps1(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < nOuterLoop; i++)
    {
        *(pOutputSignal + i) = m0;
        for (int j = 0; j < nInnerLoop; j++)
        {
            if ((i - j) >= 0 && (i - j) < quarterOfInputSignal)
            {
                *(pOutputSignal + i) = _mm_add_ps(
                    *(pOutputSignal + i), 
                    _mm_mul_ps(*(pImpulseResponse + j), *(pInputSignal + i - j))
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I was viewing the results, I saw that my SSE variant skipped some values and so on, and I think, that I'm not using properly implementation with SSE.
The algorithm should be this:
[image]

"*(pInputSignal + i - j) is incorrect in case of SSE, because it's not an i-j offset away from current value, it's (i-j) * 4 . THe thing is, as I remember it, the idea of using pointer that way is incorrect unless intrinsics had changed since then - in my time one had to "load" values into an instance of __m128 in this case, as H(J) and X(I-J) are in unaligned location (and sequence breaks)." - @Swift-FridayPie. I think that this is essential message .

Comment: Are your array sizes a multiple of 4? Are they correctly aligned? Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, my array's sizes a multiple of 4 and they are aligned (have added that piece of code). I'm not sure if I can use pointer arithmetic for sse, because have seen in examples only ones that uses ptr++, but I don't know how to rewrite that example/

Comment: At first I thought you were asking about rounding error, but are your functions not even mathematically equivalent?  Your scalar algorithm involves serial dependencies across the previous `INPUT_SIGNAL_ARRAY_SIZE` elements, right?  So that's not going to work with just aligned loads.  The naive approach might involve just doing unaligned loads from every offset.  But probably best to look for SSE convolution algorithms; this is probably an already-studied problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes I should compare time of two approaches, so algorithm should be the same, and I should use exactly that algorithm, which I have added to the question

Comment: SSE isn't "an approach" . it's a different set of available operations with their own cost and limitations, `__m128* pInputSignal = (__m128*) inputSignal;` already might be a folly because it's  mention strict aliasing breach, either  unaligned address wouldn't be supported or  performance  would be *magnitudes* lower.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie "approaches" means variants: with standart CPU and with SSE one. That line is okay. Problem with using addresses, I suppose

Comment: Thanks for changing the title, that was indeed was I was getting at with my previous comment.  The previous title was much more general, and thus only good if it was about something like making scalar code exactly numerically match vectorized code that it was already close to, or something else general.

Comment: @PeterCordes sure, you are right. Anyway, I tried to add all information about what I want to get and what I have. And I think that the problem only with bad pointer arithmetic, probably, when *(ptr + 0), for example, calculated then *(ptr + 1) is not calculated, but it's just my thoughts where could be the problem - I don't know)

Comment: If the goal is to make this faster, then for the relatively large array sizes you are using an FFT-based convolution will be an order of magnitude faster than even a SIMD-optimised naive implementation (O(n log n) versus O(n^2)).

Comment: @PaulR goal is to compare the algorigthm above using only CPU and using SSE, so we should implement that algorigthm, but now SSE variant is not correct.

Comment: @mkip: OK - I just wanted to makes sure you weren’t wasting time implementing an inefficient algorithm.

Comment: `*(pInputSignal + i - j)` is incorrect in case of SSE, because it's not an `i-j`  offset away from current value, it's `(i-j) * 4` . THe thing is, as I remember it, the idea of using pointer that way is incorrect unless intrinsics had changed since then - in my time one had to "load" values into an instance of `__m128` in this case, as `H(J)` and `X(I-J)` are in unaligned location (and sequence breaks).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie amazing! I think you are right! Can you try pls write then correct method code and I'll mark it as correct one, because frankly speaking I didn't recognise how to write it correct with that information..)

Comment: Since you care about individual floats and their order, probably best to use `const float*`, with `_mm_loadu_ps` instead of just dereferencing (which is like `_mm_load_ps`).  That way you can easily do unaligned loads that get the floats you want into the vector element positions you want, and the pointer math works the same as for scalar.  You just have to take into account that load(ptr) actually gets you a vector of elements from ptr+0..3.

Comment: @PeterCordes i think this is essential one! Can you write that logic in method computeConvolutionOutputSSE pls? Will be glad to mark your correct answer